# CVS update ignore directories from repository, namely illegal names in windows like aux

Tags: cvs, special-folders, tortoisecvs

I have trouble checking out a directory called `aux`, because that name is an illegal directory name in Windows (remnant from DOS I believe). I have no way of manipulating the repository itself.

I use TortoiseCVS, but it doesn't have the option to ignore directories that are available on the repository. Using `.cvsignore` isn't working either, because that only ignores commits.

Is this possible at all? TortoiseCVS simply says the following, which is rather discouraging:

> Tortoise Tip:  This error may be caused by having a folder and a file with the same name (apart from capitalization) in the repository. Such a repository CANNOT be checked out on a Windows file system.

The actual error from CVS is this:

> cvs [update aborted]: could not chdir to aux: Bad address

Note: I can live with a solution where I can checkout all folders, except this one. Since there are 1000+ folders, it is not trivial to just checkout all other folders manually.

Comment: Assuming you got access to the repository somehow, is removing the directory a possibility or do you need it to be part of the project?

Comment: @BurhanAli Unfortunately, I cannot remove the directory on the repository, it's a part of the repository that is readonly for me. My only access to the repos is through CVS.

Comment: That wasn't quite what I meant. My first reaction to reading the question would be to fire up a Linux VM, check out the project and remove the directory using CVS. This is only possible though if the folder isn't essential to the project. So that's what I'm asking: Is this folder needed for the project?

Comment: @BurhanAli: no, I can live without that folder. Your suggestion is to check out via Linux, remove offensive folders, copy to Windows? Tough route, but should work I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I would do:

- Fire up a Linux machine (physical or virtual, real install of live DVD, it doesn't matter).
- Check out the project using `cvs`.
- Remove the contents of the directory using `cvs rm` and commit the changes.

  - Note that cvs does not allow you to remove directories themselves unfortunately.
- Go back to the Windows machine and either check out project again or do a `cvs update`.

One thing you will need to do it add the `-P` option which will prune empty directories. If you don't add this then it will still attempt to download the empty `aux` directory.